# Не отправляются данные в базу данных SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

1.Подключаюсь к БД(тут ошибок нет всё подключается):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "register-bd";
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
$conn->set_charset($charset);

if(!$conn){
    exit("Connection field!");
}else{

}
```

2.Посылаю sql запрос на добавление данных в users

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once 'db.php';
 $login = $_POST['login'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (login,pass) VALUES ('$login','$pass')";

 $conn->query($sql);
?>
```

3.Данные получаю в html `<input>` методом `"post"`.В переменные `$login` , `$pass` введенные данные доходят, а вот уже в БД нет.

```
<form action="registration.php" method="post">     
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" name="login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="pass">
        <button type="submit">register</button>
    </form>
    
    <form action="auth.php" method="post">     
        <input type="text" placeholder="login" name="login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="pass">
        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
```

4.Пробовал использовать `$stmt` метод `execute();` `prepare();` подготавливая запрос, ничего не помогает, ошибок не выдаёт, просто будто игнорирует запись данных.

5.Название БД, что бы уточнить что ошибка не в данных самой БД.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И в файле с запросом тоже ошибок нет? .....а что возвращает `query`  смотрели?  а что будет если после запроса испытать https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php ?  ..... а какой "чистый запрос" в итоге получается - смотрели?

Comment: а, всё....понятно......... ошибки явно есть (одна точно).........и их точно увидите когда mysqli_error примените.......

Comment: Похоже, что поле с паролем у вас по другому называется и еще неизвестен тип поля id.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  постарайтесь забыть о существовнии этой функции. Это рудимент из прошлого века, который и раньше-то не было смысла использовать, а в последних версиях РНР она и вовсе бесполезна.

Comment: @Ипатьев просто не помню как посмотреть ошибку, если эта ошибка в  SQL запросе. Мне казалось пыха должна была показать, но ТС утверждает, что ошибок нет. Поэтому написал про эту функцию

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в поддерживаемых версиях PHP mysqli действительно сама говорит об ошибках в запросах. В легаси версиях надо настраивать вручную, через mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT). Но это, во-первых, гораздо проще, поскольку пишется только один раз, а не ходить за каждым запросом с mysqli_error, а во-вторых правильнее, поскольку  mysqli_error сами по себе не выводятся, то есть их надо специально выводить. А потом этот вывод остается в коде и светит ошибками на продакшене.